# Is there a way to have Heterogeneous Map In C++?

Tags: c++, buffer, void-pointers, heterogeneous

Is there a way to have a `heterogeneous` map implementation as the below with the following conditions please:

1. The types are known at run time as well as the read keys.
2. Almost zero overhead e.g. not `boost::any` that's slow for my purposes.
3. No ugly long macros.

```
class special_map;

class buffer
{
public:
    ~buffer() = default;
    buffer(const special_map& map) : m_map(map) {};

    template<typename T>
    void read(const std::string& name, T& value)
    {
        map.read<T>(name, value);
        return void();
    }

private:
    special_map m_map;
};
```

Can I use:

1. `void*` with `reinterpret_cast` please? How? Is it safe for the client/user?
2. can I use `boost::hana` or `boost::fusion`.

Thanks very much? (Please plz see conditions)

Comment: Is the list of all types used known at compile time?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes becasue at the time being it's a finite set. But I want to avoid everytime I want to add a type I have to change the code? Thanks for checking this a lot!

Comment: `boost::any` or `std::any` _are_ the safe versions of `void*`.

Comment: In that case you could use `std::variant` and ordinary `std::map`, then `read<T>` is possible, perhaps returning `std::optional<T>`. Yes, that would require listing the types and any new ones. If the list is not know, you will unlikely do better than `std::any`.

Comment: MilesBudnek and Quimby thanks so much. did this conversation finish? Are you 100% I shouldn't waste time looking please?

Comment: In a `std::map`, the first element must be sortable.  My suggestion is to create a parent class `sortable` that contains virtual function for ordering.  You can then have various derivation of `sortable`.  Use pointers to store in the map.  Don't forget that the classes must be copyable.

Comment: To me it seems your actual problem is that `boost::any` is slow, so maybe look into why it appears to be slow? I slightly doubt you can do any better though, type erasure is simply not free. Also are you sure, that is the code, have you measured?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I fail to understand? The first argument you can assume as in the code it's a string. What is the T? Can I know the T and call it's member functions with this? If you mean to say sortable is the second argument, I can only read the the sortable class, I don't what member functions it has?

Comment: @Quimby clear, thanks very much! I know C++ is strong type language but it appears that this issue should be popular, like for example in event systems, you have to always cast so you can dispatch the event. Likely I will just use boost::any or std::any.

Comment: "The types are known at run time" how that ? The types must be known at compile time. The quesiton is rather: Is it a limited set of types, then you want `std::variant` or `boost::variant`. Only if the set of types is unbound you want `std::any` or `boost::any`. And then you need to pay for what you get, so I wouldnt expect that writign your own `any` will be any faster than the already existing one

Comment: "The types are known at run time" All I want to say is you don't have a finite number of types so I exclude the variant and macros.

Comment: Create an interface base `class types_base { ... };`, and then a `std::map< std::string, std::unique_ptr< types_base >> my_types_map;`  Then add pure virtual function(s) to `types_base` and when you have a new type just inherit from it and implement the necessary virtual functions.

Comment: Are you talking a `std::map` where the first element is common, but the second element has variable type?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that internally uses `std::map` (or any map implementation of your choice) for every type `T` that we want to be able to store. From the comments, I read that it is the case that we know what types we want to store. I would *expect* the overhead of this implementation to be roughly the same as the underlying map implementation, but it is not my job to test that. *There are no funky pointer casts or use of std::variant et al in this implementation*:

```
#include <map>

template <typename ... T> class special_map {};
template <> class special_map<> {};

template <typename T, typename ... Args> struct MapAccess {};

template <typename T, typename First, typename ...Rest>
struct MapAccess<T, First, Rest...> {
  typedef MapAccess<T, Rest...> Next;
  
  static T read(special_map<First, Rest...>* m, const std::string& k) {
    return Next::read(&(m->rest), k);
  }

  static void write(special_map<First, Rest...>* m, const std::string& k, const T& v) {
    Next::write(&(m->rest), k, v);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename ... Rest>
struct MapAccess<T, T, Rest...> {
  static T read(special_map<T, Rest...>* m, const std::string& k) {
    return m->storage.at(k);
  }
  
  static void write(special_map<T, Rest...>* m, const std::string& k, const T& v) {
    m->storage[k] = v;
  }
};

template <typename First, typename ... Rest>
struct special_map<First, Rest...> {
  special_map<Rest...> rest;
  std::map<std::string, First> storage;
  
  template <typename T>
  void write(const std::string& k, const T& v) {
    MapAccess<T, First, Rest...>::write(this, k, v);
  }
  
  template <typename T>
  void read(const std::string& k, T& v) {
    v = MapAccess<T, First, Rest...>::read(this, k);
  }
};
```

So to use it, you have to list all the types that it should be able to store, e.g.

```
special_map<float, int, std::string> myMap;
```

If you try to use it with a type not listed in that list, I would expect you will get a funny compilation error, so you will know that you have to add it there :-) For example, if I try to read a bool from `myMap` I get the error

```
main.cpp:15:22: error: ‘read’ is not a member of ‘MapAccess<bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Next’ {aka ‘MapAccess<bool>’}
```

Comment: I am reading the code, but it looks perfect to me so far. Thanks so much. Can you think of any downsides please so I am aware? I should benchmark this again boost::any :)

Comment: @Vero The downside of this code that it is probably *more code* than for example a solution based on `boost::any`. And more code means more bugs... If you decide to use it, you may want to tweak it, for example to mark `read` as `const`. Maybe provide extra methods such as `size_t size() const` etc. You can see how `read` and `write` are implemented and then implement `size` etc using recursion with the `MapAccess` struct the same way.

Comment: thanks so much! Running some benchmarks. Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: I am trying to build this:
special_map<float, int, std::string> map;
map.write<double>(std::string("Hello"), 4.0);
map.write<double>(std::string("Bb"), 1.0);
but it fails with "error C2039: 'write': is not a member of 'space::MapAccess<T>'"

Comment: @Vero It fails because you are trying to write a `double` to a map that *does not* contain `double`, but only the types `float`, `int` and `std::string`. Add `double` to that list (`special_map<float, int, std::string, double> map`) and try again.

Comment: Ah missed that one ;p sorry! Thank you!! One more thing I have to do I think is also make sure the template values are unique, otherwise the recusive search might stop at one of the maps!

Comment: The recursive search will stop at the *first* matching type so having the same type occurring multiple times won't be a problem.

Comment: Aaah that's true because the write and the read follow the same path, thanks a lot!